# How to write Unit Test cases for mule custom transformer

Tags: java, junit, junit4, esb, mule

We were trying to write Junit test-cases for custom transformers in Mule.
But we were not able to call the doTransform() method in test class.

Later we realised seeing mule docs that Mule gives features for Unit test cases.
And as per the document we have extended `AbstractTransformerTestCase` which has some methods to be implemented.

they are :

```
@Override
    public Transformer getTransformer() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Transformer getRoundTripTransformer() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getTestData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getResultData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

We are now confused about following things:

1. Where to write our testing logic?
2. Where & how to Send the input to the Transformer?
3. What are we returning from the transformer ?
4. What if we are not returning anything from the transformer (transformer being the last end point in the flow) ?
5. How to "Invoke" the Test cases?
6. How to write test cases where a custom Exception is expected ?
7. In Junit testing inside eclipse we used to declare it as  `@Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)` but how to do it here in mule unit test cases?
8. How can we use existing 'to be overridden methods' inside `AbstractTransformerTestCase` ??

Please help us out. We are not understanding anything since 2 weeks what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To test transformers in Mule do the following:

- Extend `org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformerTestCase` and implement the abstract methods ([look at the test for the Base64 transformer as a good example](http://svn.codehaus.org/mule/tags/mule-3.3.1/core/src/test/java/org/mule/transformer/codec/Base64TransformersTestCase.java)). This covers the basics of the transformer.
- If there are more advanced scenarios you want to cover, like for example with different payloads or properties, then create functional test case(s) by extending `org.mule.tck.junit4.FunctionalTestCase` and create standard JUnit4 `@Test` methods to interact with the transformer(s) you will have configured in test configuration(s).

Answer (score 0):

As you start with testing,  you may as well start by employing good practices like test driven developemnt.  You will need:

- junit in actual version ( you already got it )
- modern mocking framework (I would strongly recommend jmockit as most flexible tool at the moment)

You will not need:

- abstract base test classes from mule

When you write transformer tests, you are testing that your transformer behaves properly (well,  it transforms  one object to another) - so in your test case you just instantiate your transformer and hit transform methids with  some inputs  and  execute your assertions on results.   In case your transformer  can be instantiated without mule and does not require collaboration while tranforming,  you have just plain unit test.

If you need collaboration with mule, Java EE or whatever subsystems you need to test them - here mocking comes in play.  Instead of rigging up  while service infrastructure you just provide mocks  and define expectations how your class shall collaborate with them ( you are testing your class, nor mulen or JDBC drivers ).   Here is example of unit test for another weird environment (android):

```
/**
 * shall inject assignable views   into class
 * note that mocks are specifuied as parameters
 */
@Test
public void testSimpleInjection(@Mocked final WithInjectableViews injectable,
                                @Mocked final TextView textView,
                                @Mocked final Button button) {

    // we expect that  certain methods will be called on mocked objects
    new Expectations() {
        {
            injectable.findViewById(239);
            returns(textView);


            injectable.findViewById(555);
            returns(button);


        }
    };

    // method under test
    ViewInjector.startActivity(injectable);

    // assertions
    assertEquals(textView, Deencapsulation.getField(injectable, "asView"));
    assertEquals(button, Deencapsulation.getField(injectable, "button"));
    assertNull(Deencapsulation.getField(injectable, "notInjected"));

}

// class derived from android activity,  base class is not instantiable
// in normal java environment, only on the phone or emulator but this is not
// practicable
class WithInjectableViews extends Activity {
    // shall be injected
    @InjectView(id = 239)
    private android.view.View asView;
    @InjectView(id = 555)
    private Button button;
    // shall be left alone
    private View notInjected = null;

}
```